# Concurrency Issue in ISORequestListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sonarqube, jpos

I am using `jpos` library for transaction management(Spring boot project). I am implementing `ISORequestListener` as below.

```
@Component
public class MyRequestListner implements ISORequestListener, Configurable {

    protected String var1;
    protected String var2;

    @Override
    public void setConfiguration(Configuration cfg) throws ConfigurationException {
        var1 = cfg.get("var1");
        var2 = cfg.get("var2");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(ISOSource source, ISOMsg m) {
        Context ctx = new Context();
        ctx.put("ctx1", var1);
        ctx.put("ctx2", var2);
        return true;
    }
}
```

On running `SonarQube` (code analyzing tool), I got the error message as:

> Annotate global variables with "@Autowired", "@Resource", "@Inject", or "@Value", or don’t use on Spring @Component, @Controller, @Service, and @Repository classes.
>
> Spring @Component, @Controller, @Service, and @Repository classes are singletons by default, meaning only one instance of the class is ever instantiated in the application.
>
> Such a class might have a few static members, such as a logger, but all non-static members should be managed by Spring. That is, they should have one of these annotations: @Resource, @Inject, @Autowired or @Value.

Does this cause any concurrency issue(or thread issue) or internally handled by `jpos`? What could be the correct implementation if it really causes the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a problem if you run jPOS within its own Q2 micro-kernel. If that's not the case, I'm afraid you're mostly on your own. Running inside Q2 is extremely simple, it's a one liner: `new Q2().start();` that you can run from any other framework, and then let Q2 configure your jPOS components.